# Local hardhat node throws "Error: Transaction reverted" in the terminal for transactions that pass successfully

Tags: contract-invocation, ethers.js, nodejs, hardhat

I'm developing a UI for my contract using a local hardhat node with an ethers library.
I have several different contract function calls that pass successfully and do not throw any errors in browser console but they do throw an "Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function" in the VSC terminal window that runs the node

Like so:

```
eth_feeHistory
eth_blockNumber
eth_getBalance (9)
eth_feeHistory
eth_getTransactionCount (2)
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Contract call:       Betting#appendUserBet
  Transaction:         0xb4f3b2277d18a7fcdb26ef6c85c770dd2f03c25d7e197f2a99356ec5d4a9213f
  From:                0x3c44cdddb6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12fa4293bc
  To:                  0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3
  Value:               0.427 ETH
  Gas used:            62365 of 62852
  Block #14:           0x9b3b289e7c5ebfc69c223dfcf26effac42bb0485ce75f19d83565e394e32668e

eth_call
  Contract call:       Betting#<unrecognized-selector>
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3

  Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
      at Betting.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/Betting.sol:4)
      at HardhatNode.runCall (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:616:20)
      at EthModule._callAction (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:354:9)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:188:20)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:167:17)
      at Server.JsonRpcHandler.handleHttp (C:\Users\Sabotage\Desktop\code\betting_platform\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:52:21)
```

code snippet of a contract with a function in question:

```
contract Betting {
    uint256 public fee = 1000000000000000000 wei;

    struct UserStruct {
        uint256 betAmount;
        uint256 potentialWinnings;
        string teamChosen;
    }

    mapping(address => UserStruct) public userStructs;
    address[] public userList;


    function appendUserBet(string memory userTeamChosen) public payable {
        uint256 minimumFee = 1 * 10**17 wei;
        userList.push(payable(msg.sender));
        require(msg.value >= minimumFee);
        fee = msg.value;
        userStructs[msg.sender].betAmount += msg.value;
        userStructs[msg.sender].teamChosen = userTeamChosen;
    }
}
```

snippet of a script that calls this function inside of js:

```js
import { ethers } from "./ethers-5.6.esm.min.js"
import { abi, contractAddress } from "./constants.js"

async function appendUserBet() {
    const ethAmount = document.getElementById("ethAmount").value
    console.log(`Funding with ${ethAmount}...`)
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)
        try {
            const transactionResponse = await await contract.appendUserBet(
                "kek",
                {
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount)
                }
            )
            await listenForTransactionMine(transactionResponse, provider)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    } else {
        appendBetButton.innerHTML = "Please install MetaMask"
    }
}
```

The contract has other functions but when any of them execute hardhat throws this error even if the execution is 100% successfull.
What is wrong with my code? How do I fix this error?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever gets the same problem - just ignore it. I found no solution and code still runs perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that is working well so far. I ran into the `Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function` issue just "sometimes", without any apparent reason, and other times, everything worked perfectly. So, I added the `retries` option to mocha in my `hardhat.config` file:

```
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000,
    retries: 3,
  },
```

Hope it helps.